# How to scale canvas without blurry edges?

Tags: html5-canvas, svelte, pixel

I'm attempting to make a sprite editor using Svelte and I'm able to get basic pixel drawing done, it just looks slightly blurry around the edges and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
<script lang="ts">
    let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    let ratio = 1;
    $: if (canvas && !ctx) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')!;

        const ogWidth = canvas.width;

        const canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        canvas.width = canvasRect.width;
        canvas.height = canvasRect.height;

        ratio = canvas.width / ogWidth;
        ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);

        // draw
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillRect(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }

    const onMouseDown = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        // get closest pixel
        const x = Math.floor(e.offsetX / ratio);
        const y = Math.floor(e.offsetY / ratio);
        console.log(x);
        // draw
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    };
</script>

<div class="w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center object-contain">
    <canvas
        width="16"
        height="16"
        bind:this={canvas}
        class="w-[1024px] border"
        on:mousedown={onMouseDown}
    ></canvas>
</div>
```

I could just be fooling myself, but when I look at other online pixel art editors such as Piskel, the pixels seem much more crisp.

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/01c287a93aa64328b975682800e3038f?version=3.47.0)

Comment: Is your browser or OS zoomed in? That can probably cause such issues. What browser are you using?